# All preferences gone in 2.81

Tags: customization

From 2.79 through all 2.8 beta versions up to the the "proper" 2.8, my preferences (where add-ons are set) were always the same. That was fantastic! 
With 2.81, there's a fresh start and all my add-ons are gone in preferences. Can't see a solution in file path... Would absolutely like to refer to the "old" settings file instead of copying.